# Universal analytics bigquery export: retrieving fullVisitorId from _ga cookie

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, universal-analytics

Does anyone know how to build the fullVisitorId available in BigQuery export (premium account) from _ga cookie? If this is not possible, do you know how to get the user fullVisitorId in js?

Many thanks,

Quentin

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I'd like to access a bigquery dataset with js and my key is the field fullVisitorId from the bigquery export available with universal analytics premium accounts.

Comment: Still not clear what you want to do. Why do you have to run in JS? What would you like to obtain, and how would you like to reuse? Describe the full problem. You have a device? a server? a webpage?

Comment: From a webpage I want to get the fullVisitorId of my visitor with js (js seems easier), then, based on that key I will be able to access browsing data (stored in my bigquery table) related to that current visitor. My bigquery table is based on the bigquery export from universal analytics. But I'm only stuck on how to get the fullVisitorId of a user when he visits my page, the rest is fine.

Comment: You have also access to the premium support, maybe ask them directly.

Comment: Also check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16102436/what-are-the-values-in-ga-cookie

Answer (score 1):

I guess your assumption is not totally correct, when your user access your web page on different computer, they may get different fullvisitorid, although your web page may set the same userid,  and the most important, I don't think you can get fullvisitorid with js, I think fullvisitorid is generated by google in the backend. and is not open to your web page js, maybe you can get _utma, and fullvisitorid should map to _utma