# Trouble Mapping A GA Client ID to a BigQuery fullvisitorID

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I am in the midst of a controlled test verifying the link between Google Analytics & BigQuery data. In theory the BigQuery fullVisitorId is supposed to be equivalent to the client ID. That said, the following controlled test was just completed:

- I visited an internal website with a custom source/medium of
  "nate/nate" obtained the GA client ID from the cookie (values was
  1535662810)
- I expected that the client ID would map to the
  fullVisitorId in BQ
- Unfortunately, when I query the BigQuery data set using the following query the fullVisitorId is
  6595621548070533271.

Can anyone comment on the difference that is being observed?

```
SELECT fullVisitorId
FROM [98843070.ga_sessions_intraday_20150716]
WHERE trafficSource.medium = 'nate'
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16102436/what-are-the-values-in-ga-cookie

Comment: Since you already pay for premium account, maybe try addressing these questions to the premium support. I know at least 3 other questions here, that asked the same and never got answered.